# Facebook login using access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

Is there anyway to store an access token to be used later?

IE:
user1 logs in to my app then logs in with Facebook Dialog Auth
app stores facebook access token
user1 logs out of my app
user2 logs in to my app then logs in with Facebook Dialog Auth
user2 logs out of my app
user1 logs back into my app and continues to use facebook with access token stored originally stored from the first login?

===

I should clarify a bit...
I'm trying to figure out to have multiple facebook accounts tied into my app. So that when different users login, they can access their individual facebook accounts.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly how you do it too - but this only works if you decouple 'login to my site' from 'login using facebook' - you then store the most recent access token in your database and when they log back in continue to use it until it expires, at which time you need the user to go through the auth flow again

Comment: can you post a link to some tutorial or something where you can dynamically apply the access token like we're discussing here? I have only seen demonstrations where an access token is applied with a new login.

Comment: I don't really know how to give you an example - after the user logs into your app/site via your existing login code, retrieve their most recent Facebook access token from your database and use it when making calls to the Facebook API - if it expires you'll need them to go through the facebook auth flow again (which will need them to be logged into Facebook's site/app)

Comment: okay I think I understand now. so when I want to set the token I have this: `private Facebook mFb;` `mFb.setAccessToken(TOKEN);` and it should work? Is there anything else I have to do to reapply the token and continue operating as the previously signed in user?

Comment: I should clarify a bit...
I'm trying to figure out to have multiple facebook accounts tied into my app. So that when different users login, they can access their individual facebook accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access tokens expire, over time. So you should check if it is valid when the user logs back in and handle expired access tokens when encountered in the way mentioned [**here**](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/).

If you are looking to use offline_access to extend the expiration date, that is soon going away. Now, you will have to renew the access token as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

**The offline_access permission was deprecated and removed December 5th, 2012**

Comment: isn't there an offline permission for facebook that makes the access token last indefinitely? If **user2** doesn't log into facebook I'd like **user1** to be able to log back into my app and the access token be reapplied.

Comment: The offline_access permission is deprecated and will be removed December 5th, 2012

Comment: if I used extend token, any idea how long that lasts? I'd like the user to only have to login to facebook once if they're using the same app login. The only time I would want a relog is if they log out of their current user on my app.

Comment: I should clarify a bit...
I'm trying to figure out to have multiple facebook accounts tied into my app. So that when different users login, they can access their individual facebook accounts.

Comment: Short-lived access token is around 2 hours. The long-lived one, you get when you use Server-side auth in your application, is 60 days.

Comment: Your direction has been most helpful. I think I'm going to start a new question for figuring out the rest of this. I'd appreciate it if you could provide any insight there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961421/multiple-facebook-accounts-tied-into-one-app